# Retrieve all comments to a viral video of my grandmother

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I do not have an app with the "Pages Public Content Access" permissions nor do I have one planned. My family would like to aggregate all the comments from my 100-year-old grandma's [viral video](https://www.facebook.com/KansasCityChiefs/videos/1007980389547753/) to make a collage or something special for her birthday that includes all the wonderful comments. Is there anyway I can get access to only this url or workaround to retrieve this information?

Comment: Do you own the page video posted on?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not the page it is on.

Comment: Without admin access to the page, there is not other way then.